# Android Navigation Drawer Open On Activity Create

Tags: android, android-sliding, android-navigation

I do have a simple requirement.
I want new android Navigation Drawer to open upon start of Activity.

I have tried

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerListView);
```

in onCreate of host activity.
But it didn't work.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to move the code to `onResume()` and set a flag that the action is done so it won't happen every time activity goes foreground

Comment: @kaushaltrivedi because in `onCreate` views are not displayed yet, so all of them have 0dp in all dimentions(is you measure it, you will see) and thus can't be `opened`

Comment: Well i wrote the code at end of onCreate after getting references of each object and assigning memory to each component.I dont know but do you really think that view completes it rendering just before onResume and thats why it didnt work when i wrote it at end of onCreate.

Comment: @kaushaltrivedi yes, I do. You can verify it by getting some view width and height - it probably will be 0dp even in the end of `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

put this line

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerListView);
```

at the end of onCreate it workes fine.